# Android emulator deletes my Xamarin.Android application's datas

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator, xamarin, storage

I am currently working on a cross-plateform application using Xamarin.
My application uses a SQLite database to store datas. My problem is the datas stored by my application on the emulator are deleted every time I relaunch the application on it. So I can't check if everything work well according to the data storage.

On Windows Phone, it works well.

EDIT : I'm using Visual Studio 2013. Perhaps there is an option to set to fix that but I didn't found it yet.

If you have any idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so there is a checkbox to check in Visual Studio.

We can find it to **Tools** > **Options** > **Xamarin** > **Android Settings** and activate the following checkbox : *Preserve application data/cache on device between deploys*